# C# Assembly issue relating to Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, assemblies, reference

I added a crystal report to my Visual Studio C# project. I ran the code successfully before adding the report. After merely adding the report I can no longer compile. I get the following compiler errors

```
"Error  23  'SureSalePos.InvoiceReport' does not contain a definition for 'ReportDefinition' and no extension method 'ReportDefinition' accepting a first argument of type 'SureSalePos.InvoiceReport' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\VS2010\Projects\Sure Sale Pos\Sure Sale Pos\InvoiceReport.cs 55  29  Sure Sale Pos"

"Error  20  The type or namespace name 'Engine' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  F:\VS2010\Projects\Sure Sale Pos\Sure Sale Pos\InvoiceReport.cs 16  43  Sure Sale Pos"
```

None of my libraries from crystal reports are resolving even though they are added as references visible on the right hand side in my solution explorer. the following is the code in the module generating the issue it was all automatically generated by Visual Studio

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.225
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SureSalePos {
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
    using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;


    public class InvoiceReport : ReportClass {

        public InvoiceReport() {
        }

        public override string ResourceName {
            get {
                return "InvoiceReport.rpt";
            }
            set {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        public override bool NewGenerator {
            get {
                return true;
            }
            set {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        public override string FullResourceName {
            get {
                return "SureSalePos.InvoiceReport.rpt";
            }
            set {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section Section1 {
            get {
                return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[0];
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section Section2 {
            get {
                return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[1];
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section Section3 {
            get {
                return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[2];
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section Section4 {
            get {
                return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[3];
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section Section5 {
            get {
                return this.ReportDefinition.Sections[4];
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmapAttribute(typeof(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions), "report.bmp")]
    public class CachedInvoiceReport : Component, ICachedReport {

        public CachedInvoiceReport() {
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public virtual bool IsCacheable {
            get {
                return true;
            }
            set {
                // 
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public virtual bool ShareDBLogonInfo {
            get {
                return false;
            }
            set {
                // 
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public virtual System.TimeSpan CacheTimeOut {
            get {
                return CachedReportConstants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
            }
            set {
                // 
            }
        }

        public virtual CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument CreateReport() {
            InvoiceReport rpt = new InvoiceReport();
            rpt.Site = this.Site;
            return rpt;
        }

        public virtual string GetCustomizedCacheKey(RequestContext request) {
            String key = null;
            // // The following is the code used to generate the default
            // // cache key for caching report jobs in the ASP.NET Cache.
            // // Feel free to modify this code to suit your needs.
            // // Returning key == null causes the default cache key to
            // // be generated.
            // 
            // key = RequestContext.BuildCompleteCacheKey(
            //     request,
            //     null,       // sReportFilename
            //     this.GetType(),
            //     this.ShareDBLogonInfo );
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly , u dont need to post all that junk code

Comment: What version of VS are you using and what .net framework version are you targeting (if appicable)?  What .net framework version are the crystal reports assemblies targeting?

Comment: VS 2010, .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. and the only thing i can find on the versioning for crystal reports says crystal reports 2011

Comment: So changing it to the .Net Framework 4 profile as opposed to .Net Framework 4 Client Profile fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project properties. May be it is targeted for .NET Framework 4 client profile. Change it to .NET Framework 4. Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

So changing it to the .Net Framework 4 profile as opposed to .Net Framework 4 Client Profile fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

AddReference
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource